# Azure DevOps Server Retention Policy & Deleting Old Builds

Tags: database, azure, build, retention

Couple of things Google-Fu is letting me down on at the minute so wondered if anyone can help. We've setup a brand spanking new Azure Devops Server instance and migrated our codebase across. I'd gotten our source code down to just a couple of hundred MB. This is reflected when i run the queries you find when searching to see how the database usage is broken down. I've setup a build pipeline and set the retention period min and max to just one day as we don't need to keep them around in Azure DevOps. Someone went and setup 50 odd branches the other day and people started pushing up changes. Net result was a load of builds and many artifacts now stored in Azure. Its been a few days and the builds are still there. Manually deleted builds are still there despite the retention policy being 1 day min and max.

Is there a way to get Azure Devops to instantly release the builds / artifacts to reclaim the disk space or and why are they not automagically being removed by retention policy?

I did find some stuff about cleaning down your databases logically deleted files but this did not free up the space

```
EXEC prc_CleanupDeletedFileContent 1
# You may have to run the following command multiple times, the last
# parameter is the batch size, if there are more items to prune than the 
# passed in number, you will have to run it multiple times
EXEC prc_DeleteUnusedFiles 1, 0, 100000
```

The result of this was the builds still appears but when you clicked on them it just said it couldn't find the data for build id xxx.

I next just tried deleting the build pipeline to get it delete all build history and artifact and re-created the build. The space still hasn't been freed up as the deleted build pipeline is now in the recycle bin for 29 days and i'm not seen how you can just empty the bin now. So i'm going to have 29 days of large DB backups when this could just go now.

Anyone else had this kind of problems getting going in TFS/DevOps?

Comment: We are seeing a possible problem in Azure DevOps on-prem where builds using YAML build definitions aren't ever deleted by retention policy, and also for non-yaml builds the last N builds are retained per branch... but that doesn't consider when a branch is deleted, so they hang around forever. Haven't been able to track anything down about it yet though

Comment: I am having the same issue. Don't know how to empty the build recycle bin either.
However we never startet using the storage of Artifacts within the server, because a single one of out dumps can be several GiB big. So we are using FileShare instead. That gave us the possibility of a workaround. We just deleted the Artifacts within the FileShare manually.